# Java Script issue

Tags: javascript, html

For my studies I need to create a simple script that checks if the entered data (suppose to be a 5 digit zip code) actually has 5 digits. If more or less then 5 digits entered, a alert should pop up.

So far I managed to get the alert for more and less then a 5 digit entry, but even when entering 5 digits, the alert will come up as well.

Since js is not my favourite subject I am lost, even tho it seems to be a simple thing.

Thanks in advance for answers and hints.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
function CheckZip ()
{
var content = document.forms['zipfield'].Field.value;
var length = content.length;
if (length >=5) (alert('Please enter a 5 digit zip code!'));
else if (length <=5) (alert('Please enter a 5 digit zip code!'));
else (length ==5) (alert('Valid entry'))
}
//-->
</script> 
</head> 
<body>  
<div align="left">
<p>Please enter a 5 digit zip code</p> 
<form name="zipfield" action="post"><input name="Field" size="5">
<br />
<br />
<input name="check" value="Check entry" onclick="CheckZip()" type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: So, a number will always be `<=` or `>=` a number.

Comment: Use a good title to attract the attention of people who can help!

Comment: Also, please consider indenting your code, markup, etc--it makes this significantly easier for humans to read.

Answer (score 3):

Check your condition..

When length is 5 it will go to the first `if statemenet` because you have specified it to be
 **>= 5**

So when length is 5 , it will never hit the statement `else (length ==5)`

```
if (length >5) {
      alert('Please enter a 5 digit zip code!')
}
else if (length <5) {
    alert('Please enter a 5 digit zip code!')
}
else (length ==5) {
     alert('Valid entry')
};
```

**Better**

```
if( length === 5){
   alert('Valid entry');
}
else{
   alert('Please enter a 5 digit zip code!');
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/7BYe5/)**

You have other **syntax errors** in your script

```
if (length >=5) (alert('Please enter a 5 digit zip code!'));
              --^-- Supposed to be {                    --^-- supposed to be }
```

Also you are ending  the if loop with a **semicolon ;** .. Need to remove that ..
Otherwise the statement in else if and else will never be executed

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
if (content.length !== 5) {

   alert('Please enter a 5 digit zip code!');

} else {

   alert('Valid entry');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

5 is greater than or equal to 5, so the error alert will come up.

You should be using `>` and `<`, instead of `>=` and `<=`.

Answer (score 2):

`>=` means *greater than or equal to*, `<=` means *less than or equal to*. Your problem is that if your input is exactly 5 characters long then:

```
if (length >=5)
```

Will evaluate as true, and you won't get to your else statement.